# Problems Resteasy 3.09 CorsFilter

Tags: java, jax-rs, cors, resteasy

I tried to use the new `CorsFilter` which is available in Resteasy 3.0.9. I found an example at the bottom of this page:
[Ajax request with JAX-RS/RESTEasy implementing CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589031/ajax-request-with-jax-rs-resteasy-implementing-cors)

If I define this filter in the method `getSingletons()` (of the `Application` subclass) , then my Resources don't get scanned anymore. That means that no Resources will be found and the following error occurs:

> `javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path Error Occures`

On the following page i found a description:
[javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path Error Occures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535808/javax-ws-rs-notfoundexception-could-not-find-resource-for-full-path-error-occur)

> *But basically, what this deployment option does is scan for annotations of @Path, @Provider, etc for the application. The reason is that JAX-RS will first look for classes and object in overridden getClasses() and getSingletons(), respectively. If then return empty sets, this tell JAX-RS to do scanning (per the spec).*

So JAX-RS doesn't do a scanning if i overwrite the `getSingletons()` method? Is there another way to configure this `CorsFilter` and enable the resource scanning`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> "Is there another way to configure this CorsFilter and enable the resource scanning?"

One way to keep the scanning is just to implement a [`javax.ws.rs.core.Feature`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html)

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.CorsFilter;

@Provider
public class CorsFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
        corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
        context.register(corsFilter);
        return true;
    }  
}
```

This feature will get scanned for just like all other `@Provider`s and `@Path`s.

Test with only

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

> `C:\>curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/simple -H "Origin:stackoverflow.com"
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2015 12:07:22 GMT
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: stackoverflow.com
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Content-Length: 15
>   Server: Jetty(9.2.4.v20141103)`
>
> `Hello Response!`