# Cannot access services after adding corsfilter in resteasy

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I cannot access any of my services after adding corsfilter to my ApplicationPath

this is the example

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.CorsFilter;


@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public JaxRsActivator() {
        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
        corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
        corsFilter.setAllowedHeaders("Content-Type");
        singletons.add(corsFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

If I do a curl I get this,

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/unika/usuarios -H "Origin:otherdomain.com"
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: otherdomain.com
X-Powered-By: Undertow 1
Server: Wildfly 8
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 16:18:15 GMT
```

On the server I get this

11:18:15,533 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-10) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/unika/usuarios
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]

If I take this lines off the code:

```
CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
        corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
        corsFilter.setAllowedHeaders("Content-Type");
        singletons.add(corsFilter);
```

After commenting those lines I get the following with curl

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080/unika/usuarios -H "Origin:otherdomain.com"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Powered-By: Undertow 1
Server: Wildfly 8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 16:21:09 GMT

["Bill Burke","Stian Thorgersen","Stan Silvert","Gabriel Cardoso","Viliam Rockai","Marek Posolda","Bol"]
```

But I need Access-Control-Allow-Origin

### Update

You have to manually update the classes of your rest services like

`classes.add(MyRestService.class);`

and this line

`corsFilter.setAllowedHeaders("Content-Type");`

gave me trouble access-Control-Allow-Headers, so I took that line an everything worked.

Comment: If your 'Update' section is the answer to your problem, please post it as an answer (you can answer your own question). Its more readable for people who have the same issue as you. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JAX-RS application can be configured with no web.xml and an empty `Application` subclass with `@ApplicationPath`. With this class, this is enough for your JAX-RS application to be bootstrapped, and the JAX-RS runtime will scan the classpath for all classes annotated with `@Path` and `@Provider`, and automatically register those classes with the application.

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {}
```

Once you override the `getSingeletons()` or `getClasses()` and return a non-empty set in either of them, you disable the automatic registration of classes through classpath scanning. Since you have done so, your resources are no longer automatically registered. So now you can do a couple things:

1. Just register the resources class(es) that was before automatically registered

   ```
   classes.add(MyResource.class);
   ```
2. You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29390508/2587435), which uses a [`Feature`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html) annotated with `@Provider`. The `Feature` will get registered because of the classpath scanning. In this feature is where you can register the `CorsFilter` with the `FeatureContext`.

Comment: I added this classes.add(UsuarioRestService.class);

Comment: @JuanDiego again, post it as an answer please

Comment: 2 doesnt work for me, it will stop scanning when I add the Feature