# JAX-RS : Suppress Error Message

Tags: java, rest, enums, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a class which takes enum values like Male,Female @POST . when I sent a wrong value like 'male' instead of 'Male' it shows me 400 Bad Request with this message in rest client : ***Can not construct instance of constants.Constants$GenderEnum from String value 'male': value not one of declared Enum instance names
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@718a453d; line: 7, column: 23] (through reference chain: valueobjects.ConsumerValueObject["gender"])***

My Rest End Point Looks like below :

```
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@POST
public Response addConsumer(ConsumerValueObject consumerVO)
```

Here ConsumerValueObject holds the enum.

How to suppress that error message in Rest client? I tried with ExceptionMapper but it did not help!I need to suppress the message due to security issues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Jackson response from either [`JsonParseExceptionMapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/JsonParseExceptionMapper.java) or [`JsonMappingExceptionMapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/JsonMappingExceptionMapper.java). These classes come with the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>${2.x.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Whether you have this explicit dependency or you have the resteasy-jackson2-provider (which uses the above under the hood), most likely the mappers are registered implicitly through classpath scanning. For instance you have an empty `Application` class.

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ResteasyApplication extends Application {}
```

This will cause disovery/registration through classpath scanning. If you don't have either of those dependencies, and if you are in Wildfly, I am not exactly sure how they are registered, but that is what's happening.

You could write/register your own `ExceptionMappers` for the `JsonParseException` and `JsonMappingException`

```
@Provider
public class JsonMappingExceptionMapper 
             implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {
    
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonMappingException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    } 
}
```

but from what I have tested, it's a tossup as to which one will be registered, yours or Jackson's. The mappers are put into a Set (so unordered), then pushed into a Map, so only one get's pushed in. The order in which they are pushed in like I said is a tossup.

I guess this is really only a partial answer, as I have not been able to find a solution that is guaranteed to use your mapper, aside from registering all your classes explicitly (ultimately [disabling the classpath scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30873432/2587435)), but that is a hassle.

But now the fight has been narrowed down. I will try again some more if I get a chance later

---

#### UPDATE

So this is not a solution, just a semi-proof-of-concept to show how we can get it to use our ExceptionMapper.

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;

import com.my.pkg.JsonMappingExceptionMapper;

@Path("/init")
public class InitResource {
    
    @GET
    public Response init() {
        ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
        factory.getExceptionMappers().put(JsonMappingException.class, 
                                          new JsonMappingExceptionMapper());
        return Response.ok("Done!").build();
    }
}
```

Once we hit the `init` endpoint for first time, our `JsonMappingExcpetionMapper` will register, and override the existing one, whether it is Jackson's or ours.

Of course we would not want to do this for real, it's just showing how to override the mapper. The thing I can't figure out is where to put this code. I've tried a `ServletContextListener`, in the `Application` constructor, in a `Feature` with a low priority. I can't figure it out. None of the above occur before RESTeasy does *its* final registration.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet !   implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> { } worked ! But can you tell me how to make it generic so that all these type of exceptions goes via this layer ?

Comment: Just one thing I want to mentioned  I needed to add Component annotation along with Provider annotation to make things work!

Comment: @Satyaki yeah that makes sense, as Spring probably boots after the RESTeasy bootstrap. As far as generic, I am not sure. It depends on how wide of an area you want to cover. For JSON errors, the mapper for `JsonParseException` and `JsonMappingException` should do it. For others it's hard to say, errors can happen anywhere. It doesn't make sense to have a generic response for _all_ errors that occur, as that takes away from what the client expects in certain scenarios. You need to determine what types of exception you want to handle, and do so. All I can really say.

Comment: What I wanted to do is, I have a Mapper for ApplicationException,defined by me. I want to handle Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler also converting it into my own exception . I tried to override the uncaughtException method but it did not help as it does not allow us to throw a new exception!

Comment: @Satyaki Yeah one thing to keep in mind is that only one ExceptionMapper can get called for each request cycle. This is to avoid infinite loops. If an exception occurs after or during the call of the first mapper, the exception will just bubble up to the container, and most likely result in a generic server 500.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to supress the error message or do you want to fix the actual probelm?

You can actually catch all thrown exception with a custom exception mapper like

```
@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

though, this will handle all caught exceptions and return a `200 OK` which tricks clients to think that the request actually succeeded - which was not the case! Instead of `Throwable` you should be able to catch the concrete exception (even if it is a RuntimeException) as well - maybe you have not declared it as provider or did not specify the correct exception class?

Though, as already mentioned returning a different status code for an exception is generally bad practice and should be avoided. Fixing the actual problem is probably more suitable in that case.

JAX-RS provides `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` interfaces which you can declare to un/marshall an inputstream to an object or an object to return to an output-stream. The official [documentation on MessageBodyReader](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e7053) has more detailed information on that regard.

One implementation therefore could be the following steps:

- Read the input-stream to f.e. string
- Replace all `"male"` or `"female"` tokens with their upper-case version
- Parse the string to a json-representation (using org.json.JSONObject f.e)
- Use ObjectMapper to convert the JSON representation to a Java object
- return the mapped object

This works if the input failure is just a simple upper/lower case issue. If there are typos or semantically alternative available, which are not yet in your enum, you need to put in a bit more effort.

If you, however, fail to create a proper object representation, you should return a user-failure (something in the 400 range) to the client to inform the client that something went wrong.

Comment: I tried with your solution provided above. It did not worked. I added the reference to web.xml it did not work either. What I am trying to do is whenever there is a scenario of 400 Bad Request I don't want any message to be shown on Response body. To check for the security of application I am intentionally sending it wrong value so that it fails but it's also exposing the in details of my coding which I don't want to show outside world at all.

Comment: @Satyaki as you are using Resteasy obviously, try the [example](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RESTEasyExceptionHandlingWithExceptionMapper) provided by JBoss and update the code to your needs. In principle, it is possible to supress or customize the entity-body of returned exceptions. I guess you have some issues in your configuration though