# CORSFilter is not applied on JAX-RS Application

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, wildfly

I am using `resteasy-jaxrs - 3.0.9.FINAL`.
I have two separate `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`s

```
@ApplicationPath("oauth")
public class OAuthApplication extends Application {
    final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        classes.add(RegisterResource.class);
        classes.add(TokenResource.class);
        classes.add(HelloResource.class);
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(classes);
    }
}
```

for `/oauth` based endpoints and

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        classes.add(CategoryResource.class);
        classes.add(CategoryGroupResource.class);
        classes.add(TransactionResource.class);
        classes.add(MonthlySummaryResource.class);
        classes.add(MemberResource.class);
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(classes);
    }
}
```

My filter looks like

```
@Provider
public class CorsFeature implements Feature {

  @Override
  public boolean configure(FeatureContext featureContext) {
    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
    corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
    corsFilter.setAllowedMethods("OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH");
    featureContext.register(corsFilter);
    return true;
  }
}
```

I also apply filter on my `/rest/*` resources which looks like

```
@WebFilter("/rest/*")
public class AuthTokenValidatorFilter implements Filter {
    private static final String BEARER_HEADER = "BEARER";
    private static final String COLON = ":";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(COLON);

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        if (httpRequest.getHeader(BEARER_HEADER) == null || !isValidAuthToken(httpRequest.getHeader(BEARER_HEADER))) {
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private static boolean isValidAuthToken(@Nonnull final String header) {
        final String[] tokenParts = PATTERN.split(header);
        if (tokenParts.length != 3) {
            // hash, uuid, timestamp
            return false;
        }

        final int nanoTimeStamp;
        try {
            nanoTimeStamp = Integer.parseInt(tokenParts[2]);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }

        final String hashedAuthToken = new UniqueIdGenerator().getHashedAuthToken(tokenParts[1], nanoTimeStamp);
        return hashedAuthToken.equals(tokenParts[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

When I start the application and hit the endpoint, I see

```
 ~ curl -v http://localhost:9090/application/oauth/hello
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9090 (#0)
> GET /application/oauth/hello HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9090
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Undertow 1
< Server: Wildfly 8
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 5
< Date: Fri, 26 May 2017 19:05:15 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
hello%
```

I do not see the CORS Headers sent back.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

I/m guessing you got your code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29390508/2587435). The point of this Q&A was that the OP wanted to be able to continue using the classpath scanning, i.e. keeping just

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

When you have an empty `Application` class like this, it triggers classpath scanning for classes annotated with `@Path` and `@Provider`. And all those classes are automatically registered. But once you override `getClasses()` or `getSingletons()` in the `Application` class, and return a non-empty set in either of them, the classpath scanning is automatically disabled.

So the OP was trying to find out how get they register the `CorsFilter` without disabling the classpath scanning. The solution was to use a `Feature` annotated with `@Provider`. the `@Provider` allowed for the `Feature` to be automatically discovered and registered.

In your case, you have no classpath scanning since you disabled it. So you just need to either register the `Feature` or since you are not using classpath scanning, you can just forget the `Feature`, and just register the `CorsFilter` directly in the `Application` class

```
@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    Set<Object> providers = new HashSet<>();
    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
    corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
    corsFilter.setAllowedMethods("OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH");
    providers.add(corsFilter);
    return providers;
}
```

As an aside, you're cURL request won't show the CORS headers even if you have the filter registered correctly. It's expecting to see an `Origin` header on the request.

#### UPDATE

As another aside, you need to consider the order of calls in regards to the servlet filter and the JAX-RS application. The servlet filter is called before JAX-RS. This has implications when it comes to the CORS support, which is at the JAX-RS level.

So what is going to happen is that when the client makes the preflight (CORS) request, the servlet filter will get called. And note this is just a preflight request, so any headers will not be sent, including the token header. The preflight is simply to check whether the server will allow the request. This preflight happens before the real request. This is how the CORS protocol works.

So on the preflight, the response is expected to include the CORS response headers, but with your servlet filter, it does not send this. You are only sending an unauthorized response. So the CORS will never work.

A couple solutions would be to:

1. Set up CORS support at the servlet filter level. You will not be able to use the RESTEasy `CorsFilter`. You will just need to implement it yourself.
2. Instead of doing the auth in a servlet filter, you could instead use a [JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). This way the auth and the CORS support are at the same level.

If you go with the second option, you would basically do something like

```
if (notAuthenticated()) {
    requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(401).build()));
    return;
}
```

Comment: DUDE, you saved my life, if you want you should update a reference to this for 3.1.x resteasy, because all the other 3.0.9 implementations  that I have seen broke after this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug and check if the request goes through your Filter? I'm not sure if implementing it as a Feature will work but from what I could find, most of the resources suggest to implement CORS filter as follows.

```
@Provider
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
      responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
      responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
}
```

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23631475/1849366

http://www.baeldung.com/cors-in-jax-rs

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but even in that case, the call was not going through `ContainerResponseFilter`.